# Basic BlockingCollection Producer Consumer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I have been struggling for the last few hours to get a basic implementation of BlockingCollection to work.  I cannot seem to find a tutorial in VB.NET for the life of me, so have been trying to get something working from tutorials in C#.

I just want to get a basic implementation working so I can progress to doing what I actually need.  But I am stuck.

**This is my code currently:**

```
Dim blockingCollection As BlockingCollection(Of String) = New BlockingCollection(Of String)
        Dim count As Integer = 0

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                  While (True)
                                      blockingCollection.Add("value" + count)
                                      count = count + 1
                                  End While
                              End Sub)

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                  For Each value As String In blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()
                                      Debug.Print("Worker 1: " + value)
                                  Next
                              End Sub)
```

I get no output from running this, just the following exceptions:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

I have been googling persistently for the past few hours to try and resolve this, but to no avail.  Hopefully someone here can help.

Thanks

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file and the compiler will tell you about the problem. Avoid adding a string and a number, use count.ToString().  Also shows you that it is important to *check* if a task completed successfully.  Use ContinueWith() with TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted to report exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code executes, though I don't know what it is that you want.

```
    Dim blockingCollection As BlockingCollection(Of String) = New BlockingCollection(Of String)
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                              While True
                                  blockingCollection.Add("value" & count.ToString)
                                  count = count + 1
                              End While
                          End Sub)

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                              For Each value As String In blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()
                                  Debug.WriteLine("Worker 1: " & value)
                              Next
                          End Sub)
```

Comment: All I want is a basic working example to understand it before moving on.
I get the same problems with all the tutorials I have tried

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I was working into the early hours and have been flitting between languages.
Forget in my converting from C# tutorial to vb.net code that VB is awkwardly different to every other programming language.

Problems with + rather than &